# Implementing log in alongside suPHP

Tags: php, authentication, permissions, suphp

How can a log in like feature be designed to use suPHP's file permissions. For example, if I have a website at `www.example.com` and the following two users with their own home directories, each with a php script `test.php`, and a `validateUser.php` script that belongs to another user (root, www-data, apache...) in the `/home` directory.

```
/home/
├── validateUser.php
├── user1
│   └── test.php
└── user2
    └── test.php
```

`user1` can access `user2's` script by visiting `www.example.com/user2/test.php`, and vice versa. Instead what I want, is to channel all incoming requests, using something like [mod_rewrite](http://www.workingwith.me.uk/blog/software/open_source/apache/mod_rewriting_an_entire_site), to `validateUser.php`. However, doing so will have the consequence of executing all scripts as the owner of `validateUser.php`, not the target `test.php` script.

Is there anyway to call a php script before suPHP kicks in, and then either allow suPHP to continue, or abort entirely.

---

**EDIT** This is the second bounty I am putting up. The first I gave to Gustav b/c he gave a good [partial answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032140/implementing-log-in-alongside-suphp/8136772#8136772). I will mention what I have attempted so far, and why none of them work for me.

1)I have tried using [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to redirect the URL to `validateUser.php` to either log the user in, or call whatever script they wanted to call. The problem is that I have set my virtual hosts such that each user has their own virtual site (ie. `www.user1.example.com`, `www.user2.example.com`...if this is a bad design approach, feel free to rudely point it out). Therefore, although the OS sees the file structure as above, online, the root directories are set up as such

```
VirtualHost = www.user1.example.com
├── validateUser.php
└── test.php
VirtualHost = www.user2.example.com
├── validateUser.php
└── test.php
```

Naturally I just moved a copy of `validateUser.php` into every user's directory. The problem is that now the user can delete that file and put whatever they want in there, like not require a log in at all. A way around this is to make the home folder sticky (not something I would ever recommend doing to a home folder) and make the `validateUser.php` owned by root. But now it will executed AS root since this is suPHP. That's where I gave up.

2)I could use Gustav's `mod_auth` suggestion, but I don't like that it demands the password up front (like the old school web sites).

3) I have considered a variant to 1) if I could redirect between virtual hosts. For example, restructure the virtual hosts like so

```
VirtualHost = www.user1.example.com
└── test.php
VirtualHost = www.user2.example.com
└── test.php
VirtualHost = www.admin.example.com
└── validateUser.php
```

Then use mod_rewrite to redirect ALL traffic from users to `www.admin.example.com/validateUser.php`, and if the user is logged in (or if the login is successful) the user is redirected back to the site they initially tried to log in to. The benefit of this, if it even is possible, is that suPHP won't kick in until the user is directed back to their own virtual host.

Comment: I am fairly confident my question has no solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/9561335/654789

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered implementing user authentication using using [mod_auth](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_auth.html)? If you decide to try it, there is a [guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/auth.html) that you may find useful.

The Apache 2.2 equivalents:

- [mod_auth_basic](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_auth_basic.html)
- [Authentication HOWTO](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html)

Note that the browser stores the credentials, and sends them in the header with every request you make.

Comment: I'm not too sure if this is what I am looking for, in any case, it appears to be discontinued "Compatibility: Available only in versions prior to 2.1"

Comment: That's only because it was replaced with slightly more specific modules, like [mod_auth_basic](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_auth_basic.html). If it's not what you're looking for, then no worries, just thought it might help.

Comment: This looks promising because I could create one Virtual Host which allows everyone in and use that as a log in, and all other virtual hosts are password protected with mod_auth. But could you explain how the user enters their credentials? Is it a browser controlled username/password entry? How does apache distinguished between logged in and logged out (ie. expires after 20 minutes)?

Comment: It's a browser controlled user/pass entry. I'm pretty sure the browser stores the credentials and just keeps sending them to Apache, but I'll have to check.

Comment: I just checked. It's definitely the browser that stores and sends the authentication. It adds a line like `Authorization: Basic dGVzdDp0ZXN0` to the `HTTP 1.1 GET` header with each request.

Comment: One final question, how does the authentication take place? Do I get to choose how and when the credentials are gathered/sent, or as soon as I go to www.example.com, does the browser demand the credentials?

Comment: The credentials are immediately demanded. For more control, you *can* require that only a specific subdirectory be authenticated. You don't necessarily need to require auth for the entire site.

Comment: I'll give you the bounty b/c I can use this as a temporary solution. However, I will have to play around with it for a bit before I know whether it can do what I want it to. Cheers.